# netbeans c program build fail with tdm-gcc msys

Tags: c, netbeans, msys, build-error, tdm-gcc

i have recently started to use netbeans to program in c. i usually use codeblocks. i have installed tdm-gcc and msys for this purpose.

the programs are getting compiled successfully. but on execution, it shows build failed(exit value 2).

```
    "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/f/NetBeansProjects/C_Programs'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/c_programs.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/f/NetBeansProjects/C_Programs'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o main.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/c_programs build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/structure_union.o 
build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/structure_union.o: In function `main':
F:\NetBeansProjects\C_Programs/structure_union.c:32: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/main.o:F:\NetBeansProjects\C_Programs/main.c:15: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_TDM-Windows/c_programs.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/f/NetBeansProjects/C_Programs'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/f/NetBeansProjects/C_Programs'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 657ms)
```

can somebody help me with what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `main()` functions in your project:

> […]/structure_union.c:32: ***multiple definition of `main'***

It seems there's one in `structure_union` and another one in `main.c` (line 15).

C allows only ***one definition*** of `main()`; remove one of these and it should work.

Comment: I removed the other main() function. Now it shows build successful. But it is taking too long on running the project. Why isn't the msys window opening?

Comment: Can you compare the times between NB and terminal? If you have a console project you wont get a window, it's executed within the Netbeans terminal.